# Combine Laravel, Express and Mongodb

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, laravel, express

I want to create an app and want to create an api using express and mongodb.

I'm using laravel as the main web app, so in the web app request is handle by laravel and then request send to express and then back to laravel and then render the views to users.

so I'm not using any models in laravel, it's just for routing my app and render views. but every data request is handle by express.

and i'm not deploying my api anytime soon, so after laravel is deployed, the api request is still handled locally.

what do you guys think? is this a good practice?

Comment: I'm not so sure about having Laravel do some parts and Express do others when Express already has support for routing/templating.  It feels like it's unnecessarily mixing and matching technologies.  If it's something you must do though, have you considered just using the routing portion of Laravel rather than getting the whole framework?  ex..  http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-illuminate-router-package-in-your-application

Answer (score 0):

this question can give you too opinionated answers, but for me, the simple systems is better.
if i was building your system, i would use express+mongo, and not laravel. Or probably you can use laravel with mongo, but not nodejs. Also i think, that nodejs+express will have better perfomance, than laravel

Comment: it's because i have php background and still new to nodejs and mongo, and want to learn more about express and mongo by using them as an api, but thanks anyway :)